# Regex: Find the lines with a particular TAG that contains words starting by lowercase letters

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I want to find those lines with a particular TAG that contains at least 2 words starting by lowercase letters. For example

`<span class="text_obisnuit2">I love my house</span>` (this kind)

and not

`<span class="text_obisnuit2">I Love My House</span>`

I try a regex, but not too good:

FIND: `(?:\G(?!^)|<span class="text_obisnuit2">)\s*\K(</span>*)|\u$1\L$2`

Maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<span class="text_obisnuit2">(?:(?:(?!</span>).)*?\b[a-z]){2}.*?</span>`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find Next</kbd>

OR

- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<span class="text_obisnuit2">       # literally, opening tag
  (?:                               # non capture group
    (?:                             # non capture group
      (?!</span>)                   # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't end tag after
      .                             # any character but newline
    )*?                             # end group, may appear 0 or more times, not greedy
    \b                              # word boundary, make sure we are at the beginning of a word
    [a-z]                           # 1 lowercase letter
  ){2}                              # end group, must appear twice
  .*?                               # 0 or more any character
</span>                             # end tag
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

#### Edit according to comment where OP wants to uppercase the first letter:

- Find what: `(?:<span class="text_obisnuit2">|\G)(?:(?!</span>).)*?\K\b([a-z])(\w+)(?=.*?</span>)`
- Replace with: `\u$1\l$2`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                                 # non capture group
  <span class="text_obisnuit2">     # literally, opening tag
 |                                 # OR
  \G                                # restart from last match position
)                                   # end group
(?:(?!</span>).)*?                  # Tempered Greedy Token, make sure we haven't </span>
\K                                  # forget all we have seen until this position
\b                                  # word boundary
([a-z])                             # group 1, a lowercase letter
(\w+)                               # group 2, 1 or more word characters
(?=.*?</span>)                      # positive lookahead, make sure we have a closing tag after
```

**Replacement:**

```
\u$1        # Uppercase group 1, the first letter
\l$2        # lowercase group 2, the rest of the word
```

**Note:** due to a "bug" in Notepad++, you can't use a single group and only `\u$1` for replacement

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thanks, and if I want to replace the old tag (with lowercase) with the UpperCase, how can be done?

Comment: @JustMe: The regex becomes a bit different. Find: `(?:<span class="text_obisnuit2">|\G)(?:(?!</span>).)*?\K\b([a-z])(\w+)(?=.*?</span>)`, Replace: `\u$1\l$2`. May be you could ask another question and I'll be glad to answer with explanation

Comment: super, please add this answer, too, as the second solution of your Answer. Or, add another answer with this solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This simple regex will find such text:

```
<span class="text_obisnuit2">\w+ [a-z]
```

It will look for any word followed by space and a lower-case letter.

---

[image]

Comment: It's ok, thanks. almost. But can you modify your regex, so to select all word with lowercase from that tag? By the way, must close the tag.